Unilateral laplace transform of rect(t/2)
What would be the unilateral laplace transform of rect(t/2)? We know that rect(t/2) can be written as u(t+1)-u(t-1).So what would be its unilateral laplace transform?
Should it be (exp(s)/s)-(exp(-s)/s)?
Or should we ignore the negative portion of the signal as in unilateral laplace transform the lower limit of the laplace integral starts from 0?

This is my definition of the rectangle function followed by the graphic representation and the Laplace transformation. (Varying the constant "risingedge" varies the position of the rectangle on the x-axis, "width" is the duration of the pulse).

